# Problem with not existing element in Hash Table in C

Tags: c, hashtable

I have a problem with searching for elements in a simple array in C. As long as the element exists, there is no issue, but when I try to search for a non-existent element in the 'search' function within the line:
`struct node* bucketHead = mp->arr[bucketIndex];`
the node pointer does not point to null, and the compiler shows a memory read error.
How can I fix this?

below the fragment of code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

// Linked List node
struct node {

    // key is string
    char* key;

    // value is also string
    char* value;
    struct node* next;
};

// like constructor
void setNode(struct node* node, char* key, char* value)
{
    node->key = key;
    node->value = value;
    node->next = NULL;
    return;
};

struct hashMap {

    // Current number of elements in hashMap
    // and capacity of hashMap
    int numOfElements, capacity;

    // hold base address array of linked list
    struct node** arr;
};

// like constructor
void initializeHashMap(struct hashMap* mp)
{

    // Default capacity in this case
    mp->capacity = 100;
    mp->numOfElements = 0;

    // array of size = 1
    mp->arr = (struct node**)malloc(sizeof(struct node*)* mp->capacity);
    return;
}

int hashFunction(struct hashMap* mp, char* key)
{
    int bucketIndex;
    int sum = 0, factor = 31;
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(key); i++) {

        // sum = sum + (ascii value of
        // char * (primeNumber ^ x))...
        // where x = 1, 2, 3....n
        sum = ((sum % mp->capacity)
            + (((int)key[i]) * factor) % mp->capacity)
            % mp->capacity;

        // factor = factor * prime
        // number....(prime
        // number) ^ x
        factor = ((factor % INT16_MAX)
            * (31 % INT16_MAX))
            % INT16_MAX;
    }

    bucketIndex = sum;
    return bucketIndex;
}

void insert(struct hashMap* mp, char* key, char* value)
{

    // Getting bucket index for the given
    // key - value pair
    int bucketIndex = hashFunction(mp, key);
    struct node* newNode = (struct node*)malloc(

        // Creating a new node
        sizeof(struct node));

    // Setting value of node
    setNode(newNode, key, value);

    // Bucket index is empty....no collision
    if (mp->arr[bucketIndex] == NULL) {
        mp->arr[bucketIndex] = newNode;
    }

    // Collision
    else {

        // Adding newNode at the head of
        // linked list which is present
        // at bucket index....insertion at
        // head in linked list
        newNode->next = mp->arr[bucketIndex];
        mp->arr[bucketIndex] = newNode;
    }
    return;
}

char* search(struct hashMap* mp, char* key)
{

    // Getting the bucket index
    // for the given key
    int bucketIndex = hashFunction(mp, key);

    // Head of the linked list
    // present at bucket index
    struct node* bucketHead = mp->arr[bucketIndex];
    while (bucketHead != NULL) {

        // Key is found in the hashMap
        if (strcmp(bucketHead->key, key) == 0) {
            return bucketHead->value;
        }
        bucketHead = bucketHead->next;
    }

    // If no key found in the hashMap
    // equal to the given key
    //char* errorMssg = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 25);
    //errorMssg = "";
    char err[] = "No data found.\n";
    return err;
}

// Drivers code
int main()
{
    char key1[] = "32:86:74:66:f6:7d"; char val1[] = "Number1";
    char key2[] = "43:b0:9f:42:55:9b"; char val2[] = "Number3";
    char key3[] = "a4:c1:38:46:7c:58"; char val3[] = "Numebr4";
    char key4[] = "a4:c1:38:46:7c:59";

    ;

    // Initialize the value of mp
    struct hashMap* mp
        = (struct hashMap*)malloc(sizeof(struct hashMap));
    initializeHashMap(mp);

    insert(mp, key1, val1);
    insert(mp, key2, val2);
    insert(mp, key3, val3);

    printf("%s\n", search(mp, key1));
    

    // Key is not inserted
    printf("%s\n", search(mp, key4));



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `mp->arr = (struct node**)malloc(sizeof(struct node*)* mp->capacity);` This does not initialize array elements. They are pointers with indeterminate values, a.k.a garbage. If you expect these to contain null pointers, you need to put null pointers there first. Aside: you should *not* cast the result of `malloc`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

That's because `mp->arr[bucketIndex]` returns an uninitialized element of the array, switch from `malloc` to `calloc` to get `NULL`:

```
mp->arr = calloc(mp->capacity, sizeof(struct node *));
```

Also note that this returns a dangling pointer:

```c
char err[] = "No data found.\n";
return err;
```

Which could be easily fixed:

```c
char *err = "No data found.\n";
return err;
```